# DLT vs Homography Estimation

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I'm a little confused about the difference between the DLT algorithm described [here](http://vhosts.eecs.umich.edu/vision//teaching/EECS442_2011/lectures/discussion2.pdf) and the homography estimation described [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf). In both of these techniques, we are trying to solve for the entries of a 3x3 matrix by using at least 4 point correspondences. In both methods, we set up a system where we have a "measurement" matrix and we use SVD to solve for the vector of elements that make up H. I was wondering why there are two techniques that seem to do the same thing, and why one might be used over the other.

Comment: It's exactly the same algorithm, just different notation. Neither of your sources mentions the data normalization step, which is absolutely necessary for good nymerical stability

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by normalization?

Comment: Apply to your features a transform that centers them at (0,0) and scales them to within the unit square, estimate homography on scaled features, then scale up the homography matrix.

Comment: Do you mind providing some more detail? “scales them within the unit square”? “scale up the homography matrix” by what?

Comment: Could it be that you’re talking about dividing all the entries of the matrix by entry (3,3)?

Comment: @FrancescoCallari also, in the second link, I'm not sure how to use it in practice because if I have a planar 3D of the form [x, y, 0], but obviously we can't divide by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left-right image correspondences `{p_i} <-> {p'_i}`, where `p_i = (x_i, y_i)`, etc.

Normalizing them to the unit square means computing two shifts `m=(mx, my)`,  `m'=(mx', my')`, and two scales `s=(sx,sy)`, `s'=(sx',sy')` such that `q_i = (p_i - m) / s`  and `q_i' = (p_i' - m') / s'`, and both the `{q_i}` and the `{q'_i}` transformed image points are centered at `(0,0)` and approximately contained within a square of unit side length. A little math shows that a good choice for the m terms are the averages of the x,y coordinates in each set of image points, and for the s terms you use the standard deviations (or twice the standard deviation) times 1/sqrt(2).

You can express this normalizing transformation in matrix form: `q = T p`, 
where `T = [[1/sx, 0, -mx/sx], [0, 1/sy, -my/sy], [0, 0, 1]]`, and likewise `q' = T' p'`.

You then compute the homography `K` between the `{q_i}` and `{q'_i}` points: `q_i' = K q_i`.

Finally, you denormalize `K` into the origina (un-normalized) coordinates thus: `H = inv(T') K T`, and `H` is the desired homography that maps `{p}` into `{p'}`.

Comment: Just to clarify. This step is only necessary if we are minimizing algebraic error, correct? Ie. ||Ah||. If we are using an iterative optimization technique to minimize geometric error, is this normalization step necessary? According to H&Z, geometric error is invariant to similarity transforms like the one you described

Comment: It still helps with numerical stability in that case as well.